# Interval between int months in Java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I have two `int` variables `monthFrom` and `monthUntil` which represent an interval. I want to write a method which would find if any winter month overlaps this interval. For example, if `monthFrom == 3`, `monthUntil == 5`, the method would return `false`, if `monthFrom == 2`, `monthUntil == 8` - `true`, if `monthFrom == 10`, `monthUntil= = 3` - `true`, and so on.

Being a beginner at Java I'm not sure how do I do this. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We will help you with problems, but we won't write the code for you unless you have shown a reasonable effort to do it yourself. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code like this:

```
if (monthFrom <= monthUntil && monthUntil != 12 && monthFrom >= 3)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

Or you can simplify this code like this:

```
return !(monthFrom <= monthUntil && monthUntil != 12 && monthFrom >= 3);
```

Comment: This case is not work if monthFrom = 5 and month Until =11.
It should return true but above solution return false

Comment: It should return false! winter  months are 12-2.

Comment: In india winter months are from 10 to 2 i.e from october to February

Comment: @RanjitSingh I live in Europe so Игорь Добровольський answer is correct for me.

Answer (score 2):

Joe my code helps you for your problem. 
I am using HashMap Collection to store the values of months as it contains fixed number of months corresponding to values i.e name of month.

Find my code below

```
public class FindWinterMonth {
HashMap<Integer, String> months = null;
public FindWinterMonth() {
    months = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    months.put(10, "October");
    months.put(11, "November");
    months.put(12, "December");
    months.put(1, "January");
    months.put(2, "Febuary");
}

public boolean isWinterMonth(int monthFrom, int monthUntil){
    boolean isPresent = false;
    for(int i = monthFrom; i <= monthUntil; i++){
        if(months.containsKey(i)){
            isPresent = true;
        }
    }
    return isPresent;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FindWinterMonth fm = new FindWinterMonth();
    boolean isWinter = fm.isWinterMonth(4,9);
    System.out.println(isWinter);
}
```

}

I am sure it helps you and if anyone have good and efficient solutions share with us.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given the provided rules the given code should produce the desired output:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    isWinter(3,5);
    isWinter(2,8);
    isWinter(10,3);
}

public static void isWinter(int monthFrom, int monthUntil) {
    if(monthFrom <= monthUntil && monthFrom  <  3 || 
       monthFrom >  monthUntil && monthUntil <= 3) {
        System.out.println("Winter time");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not winter time");
    }
}
```

O/P

```
Not winter time
Winter time
Winter time
```

The check applies the rules that it´s winter when `monthUntil <= 3` when `monthFrom > monthUntil` or `monthFrom < 3` when `monthFrom < monthUntil`.

As there was no clear definition i assumed the rules from `isWinter(3,5);` having to return `false` and `isWinter(10,3);` having to return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are a Java beginner and you want to fiddle with the basics for now. That is a good thing, and I encourage you to proceed.

Nevertheless, you should avoid to mess with time-related code on basic level in your more advanced programs. Time is a delicate topic and several generations of programmers have spent hours and weeks to make it manageable in Java. If you already use Java 8, there is a sophisticated date-time API in package [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

In addition, you might want to check [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) from project [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra). It provides methods for calculating overlaps between intervals.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Objects, not numbers

Better to work with objects than mere integer numbers. This makes your code more self-documenting, ensures valid values, and provides type-safety.

### `Month`

For months, Java provides the [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) class. As an [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), the class pre-defines a dozen objects, one for every month, number 1-12 for January-December.

### `EnumSet`

An [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is a special implementation of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) optimized for holding enum objects. `EnumSet` objects happen to be extremely fast to execute and very small in memory. Use that to define “Winter” as a set of months.

```
Set<Month> winter = EnumSet.of ( Month.DECEMBER , Month.JANUARY , Month.FEBRUARY );
```

As for your range of months, define that too as a `EnumSet`. Instantiating is easy as the class provides the [`range`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#range-E-E-) method.

```
//Set<Month> range = EnumSet.range ( Month.of ( 3 ) , Month.of ( 5 ) );
Set<Month> range = EnumSet.range ( Month.of ( 2 ) , Month.of ( 8 ) );
```

### Compare sets

Next we need to know if any of the elements in the `range` set are in the `winter` set. Unfortunately, there is no `containsAny` kind of method in the `Set` interface. We can get that behavior with a bit more code, creating a copy of `winter`, then calling `removeAll` to remove any matching elements contained in `range`, and finally comparing to the original `winter`.

```
Set<Month> winterMonthsNotInRange = EnumSet.copyOf ( winter );
winterMonthsNotInRange.removeAll ( range );

Boolean rangeContainsWinterMonths = (  ! winter.equals ( winterMonthsNotInRange ) ); // If different, the range contained one or more winter months.
```

Alternatively, create a set of the winter months that were in common and ask if that set is non-empty.

```
Set<Month> winterMonthsInRange = EnumSet.copyOf ( winter );
winterMonthsInRange.removeAll ( winterMonthsNotInRange );

Boolean rangeContainsWinterMonths = (  winterMonthsInRange.size() > 0 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "winter: " + winter );
System.out.println ( "range: " + range );
System.out.println ( "winterMonthsNotInRange: " + winterMonthsNotInRange );
System.out.println ( "rangeContainsWinterMonths: " + rangeContainsWinterMonths );
System.out.println ( "winterMonthsInRange: " + winterMonthsInRange );
```

```
winter: [JANUARY, FEBRUARY, DECEMBER]
range: [FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST]
winterMonthsNotInRange: [JANUARY, DECEMBER]
rangeContainsWinterMonths: true
winterMonthsInRange: [FEBRUARY]
```

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/zmjuVY).

### About `Month`

Remember, these are *not* mere strings in play. The `Month` objects are real [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) objects with data and methods combined. The all-uppercase names you see in the output above are String objects generated by the [`Enum::toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--) method. You can alternatively generate strings automatically localized in other languages via [`Month::getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) method, such as `janvier` in French for January.

If unfamiliar with the Java enum facility, study the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). They are much more powerful than enums in other languages, yet very easy to use and very handy.

Remember that you can be passing these `Month` objects and `EnumSet`/`Set` objects around your code. Minimize where you use the mere integers to represent months.

Tips:

- You may also find the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) and [`MonthDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) classes useful.
- Be aware of standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings when serializing to text.